# what should i need to use in node js stdin or stdout

Tags: node.js

im writing this code to get the input from the user:

```
label Name:
input(in);

label LastName:
input(in);

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk){
process.stdout.write('data: ' +chunk);
});

process.stdin.on('end', function(){
process.stdout.write('end');
});
```

and i am keeping getting this error "Syntax Error: Unexpected token )".
and i do not understand why.
can you help me?
thank you!

Comment: On what line does the syntax error occur?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax error you are receiveing, but for user input from the command-line, the [prompt](https://github.com/flatiron/prompt) module from nodejitsu is fantastic.

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

//
// Start the prompt
//
prompt.start();

//
// Get two properties from the user: username and email
//
prompt.get(['firstname', 'lastname'], function (err, result) {
  //
  // Log the results.
  //
  console.log('Command-line input received:');
  console.log('  firstname: ' + result.firstname);
  console.log('  lastname: ' + result.lastname);
});
```

The prompt github page has lots of examples of more complex situations involving validation etc.